# Avoid Angular 2 double two-way binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two bootstrap datepickers that represent an interval of time( one being the start date and the other the end date).
I have both of these dates binded with ngModel:

```
 <td>
                    {{'STARTDATE'|translate}}
                    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="StartDate" name="StartDate" [showWeeks]="false" (ngModelChange)="setEndDate()"></datepicker>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{'ENDDATE'|translate}}
                    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="EndDate" name="EndDate" [showWeeks]="false" (ngModelChange)="setStartDate()"></datepicker>

                </td>
```

When I change the Start Date the End Date must be changed and vice versa, depending on a selected time interval(e.g: a day, a week, a month, etc). Dates are updated in the setEndDate and SetStartDate methods.

The problem is when one variable is changed the other one is changed twice.
Any tips?

UPDATE:
Here are the Date set functions:

```
setEndDate() {
    var datediffcardinal: number = this.checkDateDiff()
    this.EndDate = new Date()
    this.EndDate.setDate(this.StartDate.getDate() + datediffcardinal)
    console.log("End")
    console.log(this.EndDate)
}

setStartDate() {
    var datediffcardinal: number = this.checkDateDiff()
    this.StartDate = new Date();
    this.StartDate.setDate(this.EndDate.getDate() - datediffcardinal)
    console.log("Start")
    console.log(this.StartDate)
}

checkDateDiff() {
    var end = Date.parse(this.wallboard.endDate.toString())
    var start = Date.parse(this.wallboard.startDate.toString())
    var diff = end - start
    var days: number = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + 1
    return days;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to choose between `[(myProperty)]` and `[myproperty]`+`(mypropertyChange)` combo.

**this is wrong** :

```html
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="StartDate" name="StartDate" [showWeeks]="false" (ngModelChange)="setEndDate()"></datepicker>
```

**this is good** :

```html
<datepicker [ngModel]="StartDate" name="StartDate" [showWeeks]="false" (ngModelChange)="updateStartDate($event)"></datepicker>
```

```js
updateStartDate(date){
    this.StartDate = date;
    this.setEndDate();
}
```

Comment: does not work. Date is not updated in the other datepicker.

Comment: It's not supposed to work out of the box. I don't know your code.

Comment: code is already updated with setStartDate and setEndDate. These are the only references to the variables.

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to do the same with endDate

Comment: It does work, if something goes wrong, it comes from elsewhere... See that [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OaNX3GtqLjM38XAcTgt6?p=preview) I made with numbers instead of date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138806/discussion-between-ricky-and-n00dl3).